# Out of stock images - Grey out if products are out of stock in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I see that there is a solution for M1. Would this work for M2?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292353/out-of-stock-images-grey-out-if-products-are-out-of-stock-in-magento-1-9-x

Answer (score 0):

Same code will work. Just add this code in app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/Magento_Catalog/template/product/list.phtml

```
<?php if (!$product->isSaleable()): {
 echo '<style>.category-products li.item .product-image img{ opacity:0.6;
 filter: alpha(opacity=60); } </style>';
 } endif;?>
```